# A “time capsule” that can last for trillions of years?

Tags: science-fiction, spaceships, universe, vehicles

The universe is dying because it has exhausted nearly all of its resources. Humans became the last species in the universe because of their resilience and sheer willpower.

And yet, humanity still doesn’t want to die. Relying on the [Big Bounce Theory](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiH8pa_84LoAhWIfXAKHft7ArwQFjACegQIDBAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBig_Bounce&usg=AOvVaw2MERJS0l3zJxSRpOD9UB-h), scientists developed a sort of “time capsule”. It was designed to hold up to 200 people, plant seeds, and animal dna. The people, seeds and animal dna would probably have to be frozen for trillions and trillions of years until another Big Bang was to happen.

**Requirements for the “time capsule”**

1. It would most likely need to be incredibly heat proof (the sheer light emanating from the big bang would probably melt most metals)
2. It needs to be airtight, at least until it could land on a habitable planet.
3. Regarding #2, it needs to be corrosion-proof as well.
4. None of the above would be possible if they placed the time capsule right on top of, or very near the epicenter of the Big Bang.
5. *A predictor system*, before the Big Bang 2.0 Electric Boogaloo happens, the time capsule needs to predict where a habitable planet will pop up in the new universe and crash land there **while** still in the old universe.

**How is it possible that a universe that literally has no more materials respawn???**

1 word, magic. Universe 2.0 now has magic, aka *Mana*. We all know how magic breaks all known laws of physics from the fictions we read. Who knew that it could save the laws of physics from nothingness?

But that’s besides the point, the most important question; how do I design, build and finally, “pilot” such a thing?

Ps: this is a crudely drawn representation of what I think may happen: [image]

Comment: you might want to get rid of the science-based tag, the universe and processes you describe are really not based on current science

Comment: @SilverCookies Thanks, I wouldn’t have noticed it without you telling me.

Comment: The main problem is that the big bang happens everywhere and includes all space as far as we can tell. So its not some sort of explosion that happens somewhere in a preexisting space. The best bet would be to have access to some form of hyperspace, but then then question is dependant on the properties of that hyperspace.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want. We cannot possibly predict every single thing such a capsule has to endure. On those time scales, there is no corrosion proof or air tight. Gases are quite small and can enter and exit basically any material. Could you share with us your research so far? What events do you account for specifically?

Comment: @Raditz_35 From my understanding on the Eternal Return theory: Once the universe dies it will collapse into a singularity from which another Big Bang will occur. On your other questions,  the capsule will probably have to experience everything that happened from the start of the universe to until the Earth is habitable. The planet in which I’m planning for the capsule to land on will have a similar geological and cosmological history to Earth.

Comment: "magic" is right. there are numerous problems with this, starting with the fact that there is nowhere this capsule could be except as part of the singularity, as space does not exist anymore. the BB is not like a supernova, expanding into surrounding space. it's *space itself* explosively expanding.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the answers to this question on Physics SE : [Did the Big Bang happen at a point ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point).  It will possibly explain to you why waiting for a second Big Bang won't work.

Comment: Why is this getting VTCs as off-topic? Just because it relates to physics doesn't mean this isn't a better place for it. Consider any other physics-based question on here, or any biology, or astronomy, etc.

Comment: Note that trillions of years isn't *anywhere* near the amount of time you'll need to wait for the next Big Bang - it's not even a *rounding error*.  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe#Time_frame_for_heat_death) Anything you can create is unlikely to survive due to black hole evaporation, and quantum fusion, and theoretical proton decay (among other things).  That said, if you only need to survive a trillion years, note that the smaller Red Dwarf stars can take up to 30 trillion years to cool.

Comment: If you want to know more about the Big Bang, I'd recommend PBS Spacetime's playlist on [The Big Bang & Cosmic Inflation](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsPUh22kYmNCc3WCKb5yF136QSRf0xErm).

Comment: Your point 1 is a hard stop: the early universe would destroy *literally* everything, not just "most metals". Similarly with 4: literally everywhere is the epicentre of the big bang.

Comment: +1 for the excellent drawing. I absolutely love it :)

Comment: You might be interested in [Tau Zero](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/240617.Tau_Zero), which is pretty much what you described, but by accident. They survived for bazillions of years due to relativistic effect of time dilation (i.e., time passed much slower for them than for the rest of the universe).

Comment: I'll apologize for the scientist's remarks. They mean well, but they think they know everything just because they are all read up on certain subjects. The truth is nobody actually knows what is going to happen. Shame on those who actually think they know. It is pure arrogance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of trying to freeze something for that long and have it remain viable, I would suggest that you could consider hiding away under the event horizon of a rotating massive black hole.

There are a lot of interesting things you can potentially do with black holes that I won't go into here, but there are a few important things.

- The event horizon of a very large black hole is a surprisingly benign thing... you can cross over it without being mangled by tidal forces as you would in a much smaller black hole.
- Black holes are exceedingly long lived... there's no danger of even massing as little as our sun evaporating within your trillion-year limit.
- The enormous mass of a black hole causes relativistic time dilation, so if you were close enough (and, of course, well within the event horizon) those trillions of years could pass *outside* without you really noticing.
- There's a possibility that black holes could persist through a new big bang: [Persistence of black holes through a cosmological bounce](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3796).

In our universe, it would appear that once you've crossed an event horizon that's where you'll stay until you get reduced to a spray of radiation by the eventual collapse of the black hole in the far, far future.

In your Universe 2.0 though, magic exists, and that means there's scope for travel through an event horizon. You tweak that particular bit of handwavium to prevent time travel, but (possibly limited) FTL would be just fine, and so the contents of your black hole can simply pop out when it seems like a good idea.

Discovery of the news laws of physics can be made by the "time capsule" spaceship inside the event horizon, which can then cross the event horizon and investigate the new universe. If nothing interesting is immediately available, they can return to the highly time-dilated orbit they survived the end of the last universe in and allow large amounts of time to pass outside until the local environment becomes sufficiently benign or interesting to make it worth leaving for longer periods of time.

Comment: I like this answer. Just a few questions, How long could a massive black hole hope to last and could it fit within my timeframe?

Comment: @Inthenameofthestory there's an equation on the wikipedia page for [hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Black_hole_evaporation) if you wanted specific figures, but a solar mass black hole will last for approximately 10^64 years (and remember that a trillion is 10^12) and massive black holes will last for much, _much_ longer than that.

Comment: David Brin's short story [The Crystal Spheres](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12298550-the-crystal-spheres?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=ScYRcsZoUm&rank=1) has a series of alien communities doing just this in order to have someone to talk to.

Comment: This is extremely speculative, but as long we are not very science-based, that a +1 from me.

Comment: My thought spontaneously. "Inside a black hole you would be *really* safe." I was only half sarcastic. I mean, being spaghetti is better than not being at all, right? On the other hand you may find yourself frozen in the midst of a screaming downfall, or smeared into 2 dimensions on the surface of the event horizon, but *still...*

Comment: The movie "Interstellar" could probably contribute with some inspiration to this approach

Comment: Relevant physics question... any object inside the event horizon can only go down towards the singularity and has no way to go back up, but I assume the closer it is to the event horizon, the slower it will be forced down. In extremis, an object that is arbitrarily close to the event horizon could take an arbitrarily long time to spiral down. Could it be overtaken by the shrinking event horizon as the black hole radiates away its mass, and find itself back outside?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica with a very large black hole, the tidal forces as you cross the event horizon are surprisingly mild. You could fly across it without noticing. The same is definitely not true for a much smaller one, however.

Comment: @Hene I'm reasonably certain that you can't safely float out, though the reasons for why escape me right now. I'm sure the question has been usefully answered by someone elsewhere who actually knows their physics, but I can't remember anywhere helpful offhand.

Comment: Don't forget they can see outside the black hole from inside it.

Comment: @user253751 infalling light will also be subject to interesting relativistic effects. Not sure exactly what you'd see, or when...

Answer (score 27):

**A Pocket Dimension**

Scientists learn how to create pocket universes. Being a separate universe even if somewhat compact, it's time flows differently to the main universe and can be controlled. This means the inhabitants can be effectively frozen in time and sample the main universe once for a fraction of a second every billion years or so time is effectively sped up passing a trillion years every minute or so.

Once a new universe forms, time can altered down while searching for a new planet or materials to create a new human habitat.

Pocket universes are a common trope in many scifi and fantasy series from Doctor Who to Dungeon and Dragons.

Comment: Pocket universes need a lot of power, don’t they?

Comment: @Inthenameofthestory might explain how all the resources of the _entire universe_ got "used up" in your backstory...

Comment: If OP has a story involving a Big Crunch, then there's no other possibilities, since the Universe will collapse in a single point, you have to be outside "normal spacetime" to avoid being dragged.

Comment: In the final book of the series _The Three Body Problem_, _The Dark Forest_, and _The End of Death_, there is a pocket universe. The mass that cosmically-many species had removed from the universe to live in pocket dimensions had decreased the mass of the regular universe enough to turn it from closed to open.

Comment: I believe some physicists have suggested that a black hole is a pocket universe, since nothing can get out of it.  So all you need to do is design something strong enough to withstand the tidal forces of crossing an event horizon, and voila!  Instant Pocket Universe!

Answer (score 8):

You're already talking about Human society existing towards the end of the universe. This is an excessively long time by any standards to even think that current technology has any real meaning. So a major handwave in the style of any technology sufficiently advanced is indistinguishable from magic is probably acceptable.

Examples of such handwaves from existing fiction are;

1. [Tau Zero](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/240617.Tau_Zero) - Go faster. You don't need to store that much
   oxygen or worry about corrosion if in your frame of reference very
   little time is passing. Whizzing around the emptying universe at
   very close to light speed will do that for you.
2. [Across Realtime](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/167844.Across_Realtime?from_search=true&qid=9lOfjvDoqr&rank=1) - Stasis bubbles called "Bobbles" are for all intents
   and purposes single use force fields that last as long as you need
   them. Jump in, switch it on, an bingo you're there.
3. [Flood](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2111634.Flood?from_search=true&qid=JRq1M86Dav&rank=3) - Pocket Universe. While being mostly an aside to the main story, Arc3
   in Flood leaves a flooding earth behind by tucking itself into a
   pocket universe and heading out across the stars. Nudge the effects
   a little and your pocket universe can actually become the seed of
   the next one.

Comment: I haven't read Tau Zero, but a similar effort would be to orbit a super massive black hole just outside the event horizon as close to the speed of light as you can get.

Comment: Accelerating your entire star system (and maybe some nearby ones) to close to the speed of light would let you enjoy nice baryonic matter even after all the stars have gone out and you are simply waiting for everything to decay.  There was a I think Phoul Anderson story like this - not sure if it was Tau Zero where a star creature accidentally did this as a distraction to eliminate its rivals and eventually the star system returns to its original position after everything has decayed.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Interesting. I always thought that the tidal forces would be too strong close to the event horizon but apparently [they aren't for supermassive black holes.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/158149/72043)

Comment: @MichaelRichardson You can't orbit arbitrarily close to the horizon. The innermost stable orbit is still some distance out, which is the closest orbit in which an object can stay without constant acceleration. Unsure how much time dilation you get in this orbit, but it probably won't be enough to pass trillions of years quickly enough.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to pass any physical objects forward into the next universe. Instead, use the new universe as a machine to make them for you.

Humanity creates a device which predicts (or causes) a new universe. The device perturbs the state of the early new universe just ever so slightly and perfectly to ensure a habitable planet forms around a habitable star upon which evolves humans, plants, and animals.

The calculations required are outrageous, but if humanity (or whatever counts as humanity) has survived the $10^{40}+$ years into the [Black Hole Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe#Black_Hole_Era) their technological advancements and computing power would be equally outrageous.

A similar idea is used in [Greg Egan's *Diaspora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora_(novel)) where...

> humanity has been fully digitized. After learning all they can about our universe, they decide to "travel" to neighboring universes by injecting, particle-by-particle, a machine which can make a machine which can make copies of themselves.

Alternatively, humanity perturbs the new universe to leave the plans for itself in the [Cosmic Background Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_background_radiation) in the hopes that a future advanced civilization will find those plans and recreate humanity.

If they're really good and really specific, they could recreate an exact duplicate of people at the moment of their encoding including all their memories; presumably with some tweaks to survive in the new universe's physics. In effect, humans would "go to sleep" in their old universe and "wake up" in the new universe. Like the [philosophical Swampman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swampman) which is an exact duplicate of, but has no continuity with, the original person.

## See Also

- PBS Spacetime's [How Will The Universe End?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qg4vb-KH5F4)
- PBS Spacetime's [The Big Bang & Cosmic Inflation playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsPUh22kYmNCc3WCKb5yF136QSRf0xErm)
- Kurzgesagat's [The Black Hole Bomb and Black Hole Civilizations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulCdoCfw-bY)
- PBS Spacetime's [Are There Infinite Versions Of You?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT110-Q8PJI&t=3s)

Answer (score 4):

**If you are have an infinite universe, there is no need for a time capsule.**

[The Poincaré recurrence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem) already guarantees that given an infinite universe (or equivalent) any given state of existence with be repeated an infinite number of times. So, you can count on the reproduction of our world with the same people on it having our memories too. One could quibble that this is not the same thing, but those in that other universe will believe it to be the same thing, including version we they remember having built the time capsule and living through the big crunch and big bang.

Try to remember that infinite is not at all like just having lots and lots of zeroes.

Comment: If the exact same universe repeats, is it really a new universe or is it just the same one?